# Keep text the same while keeping special characters

Tags: objective-c

i have a text that contains end of lines; i would like to have that text introduced into a NSString and still recognize the end of line.

i.e. i don't want to have to place a "\n" at the end of every line.

how can i do so in Obj-c?

Comment: Where does that text come from? A text view? And what's the problem? `NSString` should be able to handle line breaks.

Comment: i copy-paste from a html page

Comment: Then copy it into a file in editor. Lot of editors prevent EOL character saving. I prefer TextWrangler. You can highlight control chars and check if they are LR/CF. Then you may load the string from file. If this is how you can do it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to hold the text using an `NSArray`, each element of which is a separate line.  You can use `[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet%3a)) for that:

```
NSString *str = @"hello\nworld";
NSArray *lines = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```